# How to repeat a macro code for fixed number of rows in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I'm totally new to macros and VB so would be grateful for any help. 
I have excel data in this form:

```
Clip    PSNR-codec1     PSNR-codec2     Bit Rates 
Video1  29.426086       29.220891       94357
Video1  31.207342       31.703124       322832
Video1  34.474587       34.255598       633468
Video1  36.445279       35.479189       936961
Video1  39.093937       36.4768         1539093
Video2  41.156012       37.295318       326742
Video2  43.355358       37.684239       604494
Video2  29.95337        29.30644        1218206
Video2  32.040252       30.837518       1809751
Video2  34.194409       32.774954       2387549
Video3  35.495356       33.806537       1567065
Video3  36.395173       34.544676       2173151
Video3  37.077718       35.234943       3094348
Video3  35.681498       36.036972       3240981
Video3  171.661771      83.104314       3355959
Video4  171.247791      96.978608       5103370
Video4  185.239286      128.064048      6636778
Video4  189.115735      115.418461      8150015
Video4  185.35225       154.3189011     2345629
```

My requirement is to create a chart of type "XYScatterSmooth" in a **separate sheet for each video**. The graph should have bit rates on X axis and PSNR on Y-axis. Going forward , we will have data for more videos too. So how do I write a macro which will repeat these steps for each video (i.e Loop should repeat for every 5 lines . 5 lines of data is fixed number)

Excel Version: 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me with the sample data you provided.

Put all your data on sheet one, delete any other sheets. Your data needs to start on row 2 (as above). The macro will ask you the total number of videos (I find this easier than looping until an empty cell), then create the charts on a new sheet. It names the sheets Video1, Video2, etc.

Let me know if it works out for you.

```
Private Sub BitRateCharts()

' Data should be on Sheet 1. Delete all other sheets.


    Dim nVideoNum As Integer
    nVideoNum = 1

    Dim n As Integer
    n = 1

    Dim nStart As Integer
    nStart = 2

    Dim nLast As Integer
    nLast = 6

    Dim nVideos As Integer
    nVideos = InputBox("How many videos?")

    Dim nSheetNum
    nSheetNum = ActiveSheet.Index

    Do Until n > nVideos

    nSheetNum = ActiveSheet.Index
        If nSheetNum = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count Then
            Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "Video" & nVideoNum
        Else
        End If

            ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
            ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
            ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$B$" & nStart & ":$D$" & nLast & "")
            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Sheet1!$D$" & nStart & ":$D$" & nLast & ""
            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet1!$B$" & nStart & ":$B$" & nLast & ""
            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = "=Sheet1!$D$" & nStart & ":$D$" & nLast & ""
            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "=Sheet1!$C$" & nStart & ":$C$" & nLast & ""
            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""PSNR-Codec1"""
            ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "=""PSNR-codec2"""

            n = n + 1

            nVideoNum = nVideoNum + 1

            nStart = nStart + 5
            nLast = nLast + 5
    Loop

    MsgBox ("Macro Complete.")

Exit Sub

ErrMsg:

    MsgBox ("Error encountered. Macro could not complete.")


End Sub
```

Comment: Had another question: In the above case I know the name of the first sheet - 'Sheet1'. But now I'm writing a more generic code where I don't know the name of the first sheet, SO I get it using the macro Name1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Name Then how do i use the variable "Name1" in the loop statement "ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$B$" & nStart & ":$D$" & nLast & "") to select the range?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but it should just replace Sheet1. So it should look like this: "ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("" & Name1 & "!$B$" & nStart & ":$D$" & nLast & "")